# ag-Grid SSRM - Server Side Preloaded Pagination

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm using ag-Grid Enterprise (31.0.0 in vanilla JS) with a server-side row model ([SSRM](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/server-side-model/)). Everything is working well and rendering paginated pages numbered from 1 to 5. However, I'd like the grid to initially load data starting from page 3.

I've looked through pretty much everything I can about setting grid options and the lifecycle of grid events. The only solution anyone seems to offer is changing pages through the onFirstDataRendered event.

```js
function onFirstDataRendered () {
  gridOptions.api.paginationGoToPage(3);
}
```

<s>This would be fine, but `setServerSideDatasource(datasource)` already triggers an initial request to populate the grid, meaning calling `paginationGotToPage(3)` is firing a second request and doubling the initial load time.</s>

**Edit: This is actually not fine, because the function only works if a page has already been visited. For example, trying to call this function to load page 5 first loads page 2, then 3, then 4, and finally 5. Only then can you jump to page 5 from another page with the function.**

Hardcoding the request does pull the paginated data I'm looking for, but it keeps the pagination labeled "Page 1 of More" despite this being exactly what's passed when you *click* to the next page or call `paginationGoToPage` directly.

```js
data: {
  request: {
    startRow: 50,
    endRow: 100
  }
}
```

I thought about having this data default on the initial load and finding a way to trick the navigation into displaying the correct properties, but I also can't find any way to modify the `params` property being passed to `getRows()`. This means that *every* request is being sent with the forced request data, so this is still leading me to a dead end.

---

### TL;DR: Need to simulate "paginationGoToPage" before the first server-side data is rendered into the grid.